# how to get updates on a 'TextField'?

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to separate each 3 string in text formfield and show it on
i've already tried `regex` i can get it in terminal but i can't show it in textformfield that make it look like terminal ,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OTTe.png) 
in left hand side i have exactly what i want when i print it , but right hand side  i have my textformfield

i want to show it exactly like terminal but in textformfield
here is my code
if you need more information please let me know

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AddTransication extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddTransicationState createState() => _AddTransicationState();
}

class _AddTransicationState extends State<AddTransication> {
  RegExp reg_ex = new RegExp(r'(\d{1,3})(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))');
  Function mathFunc = (Match match) => '${match[1]},';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Test Screen"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            textColor: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text("Save"),
            shape: CircleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Form(
          child: Column(
            children: [emailField(reg_ex, mathFunc)],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget emailField(reg_ex, mathFunc) {
    return TextFormField(
      onChanged: (str) {
        String result = str.replaceAllMapped(reg_ex, mathFunc);
        print(' $result');
      },
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Email Address',
        hintText: 'you@example.com',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## update !

i also want it to return a valid int like when i write 1000 it should return 10,000, i already do that with regex but i want to show it in there

Answer (score 0):

The way you want to show the text is called "Masking of Text".
There is a library out there which can help you to make such types of texts.

Lib 1: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_masked_text

Lib 2: https://pub.dev/packages/mask_text_input_formatter

You can use any of these Libraries to solve your problem. Good Luck.

Comment: i want something like when input is 1000 only return 1.000 and when it is 10000 return 10,000 ,how to do that? the last result did that but new result only separates number it means when i write 10000 it returns 100,00 , also packages have some errors

Comment: it would be better if i could show what regex returns but in textfield